# Why am I getting these errors and how to fix them?

Tags: python, proxy, handler

When I run this script I get a ton of errors.
    import urllib, urllib2

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': '127.0.0.1',
    'https': '127.0.0.1'
})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# this way both http and https requests go through the proxy
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
```

I don't really understand what these errors are, hence why I am asking. Here they are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Craig.py", line 10, in <module>
    urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 501: Not Implemented
```

Update:
After I added the ports I got these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Craig.py", line 10, in <module>
    urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

Comment: Your proxy server is not handling proxy requests.

Comment: So what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Making sure you are actually using a proxy on localhost port 80 rather than something else? Or if your proxy is running on a different port, to use that port? This is **not**, however, a Python problem.

Comment: This is not a programming question. This relates to setting up a local proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a local proxy?

If you are, it's probably not running on port 80. The default port is 3128.

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:3128/',
    'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:3128/'
})
```

Comment: Ok, it may have worked but I got more errors as you can see up top.

Comment: Are you running a local proxy?

Comment: What port is it running on? Are you running a local web server? The error message for port 3128 is *connection refused*, so the local proxy is not on 3128. The message for port 80 was *method not implemented*, so there was was something listening there, but it didn't support proxying.

Comment: When I run on port 80 i get a non responding connection error

Comment: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>                                                          I get this error as well as the one on top.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, this (StackOverflow) isn't the appropriate place to seek help setting up your proxy.